# php - how to get the img url from a href using loadhtml

Tags: php

how to get the img url from a href url using dom loadhtml ? i try using $link->nodeValue to get the img src url but is not working

Example url source:

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="www.google.com/test.jpg" />Photo NodeValue</a>
```

My php code:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ----------------------- Get URLs From Source
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function getVidesURL($url) {
   $web_source               = $this->getSource($url);

   if($web_source != '') {
    $Data                     = $this->Websites_Data[$this->getHost($url)];

    preg_match($Data['Index_Preg_Match'], $web_source, $Videos_Page);
    $Videos_Page              = $Videos_Page[$Data['Index_Preg_Match_Num']];

    if($Videos_Page != '') {
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     @$dom->loadHTML($Videos_Page);

     $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

     foreach ($links as $link) {
      $Video_Status        = "";
      $Video_Error         = "";

      $Video = array(
       "URL"       => $link->getAttribute('href'),
       "Title"     => $link->getAttribute('title'),
       "MSG"       => $link->nodeValue,
      );


// Get Image URL Start
      $dom = new DOMDocument;
      @$dom->loadHTML($Video['MSG']);

      $Video_Image = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
      foreach ($Video_Image as $Image) {
       $Video = array(
        "IMG"       => $link->getAttribute('src'),
       );
      }


      $Videos_URLs        .= $Video['IMG'] . '<br />';
     }
// Get Image URL Stop

     return $Videos_URLs;

    }
   }
  }
```

The only problem of my code is i don't know how to get the img url from a href

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small function that can pull out image sources from an HTML input:

```
<?php
  echo PHP_EOL;
  var_dump(getImgSrcFromHTML('<a href="www.google.com"><img src="www.google.com/test.jpg" />Photo NodeValue</a><div><img src="www.google.com/test2.jpg" /></div><table><tr><td><img src="www.google.com/test3.jpg" /></td></tr></table>'));
  echo PHP_EOL;

 function getImgSrcFromHTML($html){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  $imagepPaths = array();
  $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  foreach ($imageTags as $tag) {
    $imagePaths[] = $tag->getAttribute('src');
  }
  if(!empty($imagePaths)) {
    return $imagePaths;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
 }
```

Hope this helps.